# Как нормально прибить активити, что-бы пользователь ничего не заметил

Tags: android, activity

Я хочу убить активити при переходе на другую. Делаю я это таким способом:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
LoginActivity.this.finish();
startActivity(intent);
```

На эмуляторе вроде все нормально, но когда я начинаю тестирование на реальном устройстве, то мне видно когда активити удаляется, это сложно описать по-человечески как я это вижу, но визуально заметно когда при старте приложения у меня умирает активити. Потом я прочитал что можно такой способ реализовать:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

но тогда никакая активити не убивается. Эти все делается только с одной целью - что-бы пользователь не смог кнопкой `назад` вернуться на самое первое активити. Первый способ рабочий, но визуально все видно, а второй способ вообще не работает. 
Какое поведение у меня сейчас A (login activity)->B(main screen activity)->C(message center activity). Что у меня сейчас получается - после того как пользователь залогинился (login activity), он переходит на второй экран (main screen) с которого он может перейти в центр сообщений. Текущее поведение программы - с центра сообщений можно кнопкой назад перейти на main activity (тут меня все устраивает), но вот дальше я могу перейти на экран логина, а мне это не нужно, нужно что-бы только при нажатии на кнопку логаута я выходил на экран логина. Я честно говоря не знаю что нужно сделать, что-бы программа работала как нужно.

Comment: А что должно происходить при нажатии на кнопку "назад"?

Comment: ну я хочу что-бы приложение сворачивалось, я так и не нашел как его закрыть) просто сейчас пользователь может возвратиться на любую активити кнопкой "назад".

Comment: Это стандартное поведение кнопки "Назад" и не надо его менять. Она для того и существует.

Comment: то есть пользователь по-умолчанию может лазить по всем активити только нажимая одну кнопку "назад"?

Comment: Не по всем, а только по тем, на которых был ранее, пока не вернется на рабочий стол. Это как кнопка "назад" в браузере.

Comment: я так понимаю что ничего изменить и усовершенствовать нельзя)) ладно спасибо за то что объяснили, придется немного логику приложения поменять

Comment: Почему нельзя? Можно переназначить кнопку "назад" (не знаю как). Но не знаю, как к такому относятся другие люди, а я такие приложения сразу удаляю.

Comment: что означает переопределить? типа назначить ей другое действие? я вот думаю может просто при нажатии на кнопку назад сворачивать в трей, если удастся такое сделать)

Comment: Лучше сформулируйте вопрос так, что бы было понятно - что у Вас происходит и какое поведение требуется. Типа: я открываю активити `A->B->C` и активити `B` должна удалиться из истории, и из `C` я должен вернуться в `A`. Это сделать можно и не возбраняется.

Comment: обновил вопрос)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно просто убрать анимацию удаления activity. Самый простой способ:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainScreen.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Comment: спасибо большое, это именно то что я искал, потому-что было не очень красиво когда активити закрывалась с видимой анимацией

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko Незачто)

Answer (score 0):

Решил сделать так, что-бы при нажатии на кнопку назад приложение сворачивалось в трей, нужно написать такую штуку:

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startMain);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

этот кусок кода будет ловить нажатие на кнопку назад, либо можно так написать:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
        Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startMain);
      }
```

хотел вставить источники, но пока искал и пробовал, то потерял страницы. Надеюсь кому-то поможет.

P.S. Вероятнее всего на СО есть такие вопросы, но я почему-то не нашел их (данный код был найден на англоязычном источнике). Я буду не против если мне сюда скинут ссылки на сам СО что-бы я смог дополнить свой ответ.